# How to run ms access database in jar using java 8 ucanaccess

Tags: database

I have develop a program in java using eclipse, its a JTable that would connect to my ms access database, all of the data from my ms access table will be shown in my JTable in a click of a button.  My program works fine every time i run it in eclipse.  My problem is that, when i export it and make a runnable jar file and click that created jar file this message appears:

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:ucanaccess://SUGGESTION_SOURCE_FODEL/suggestionTableFinal.mdb

SUGGESTION_SOURCE_FODEL is the folder where my ms access database table is located and suggestionTableFinal is my ms access datbase table.  Any help would be much appreciated!  My code are as follow:

```
public void()
{
try
                                        {
                                            reloadDataSuggestion();
                                            model = new DefaultTableModel(data,columnNames);               
                                            mainJTableSuggestion.setModel(model);              
                                            Dimension tableSize = mainJTableSuggestion.getPreferredSize();                 
                                            mainJTableSuggestion.getColumn("SUGGESTIONS").setPreferredWidth(Math.round((tableSize.width - 220)* 1.20f));
                                            DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
                                            centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment( JLabel.CENTER );
                                            mainJTableSuggestion.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer( centerRenderer );   
                                            TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
                                            mainJTableSuggestion.setRowSorter(sorter);  

                                            st1.close();    
                                            rs1.close();                                                
                                        }
                                        catch(Exception e1)
                                        {
                                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1 + "This is my Error");
                                        }  
}

public void reloadDataSuggestion() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException 
{                           
    try
    {
        columnNames.clear();
        data.clear();

        String DBPAD = "SUGGESTION_SOURCE_FODEL/suggestionTableFinal.mdb";
        String DB = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + DBPAD;   

        con1 = DriverManager.getConnection(DB, "", "");            
        st1 = con1.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        String sql = ("SELECT * FROM suggestionTableFinal");
        rs1 = st1.executeQuery(sql);       

        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs1.getMetaData();

        int column = rsmd.getColumnCount();                         

        columnNames.addElement("Submitted");           
        columnNames.addElement("ClientNames");
        columnNames.addElement("SUGGESTIONS");
        columnNames.addElement("DateActed");    
        columnNames.addElement("Number");
        columnNames.addElement("SuggestionAction");

        while(rs1.next()) 
        {
            Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>(column);
            for(int i=1; i<=column; i++) 
            {                   
                 row.addElement(rs1.getObject(i));                   
            }
            data.addElement(row);      
        }     

        showDataToTextFieldsFromJTableConnectedToDataBase1();

        rs1.close();
        st1.close();    

        totalNumber = 0;
        totalNumber1 = 0;

    }    
    catch(Exception e1)
    {
        final JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane("<html>" +"<font color=\"#FF0000\">" + "<b><html><span style='font-size:1.2em'>" + e1);
        final JDialog d = pane.createDialog((JFrame)null, "TitleFinal1");
        d.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        d.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        d.setVisible(true); 
    }          

}
```

Comment: What happens if you use `Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");` before calling `DriverManager.getConnection(...)`?

Comment: Thanks! It solved my problem, Silly me i forgot to indicate my driver.  Thanks again!